# How to set specific year in calendar?

Tags: android

[image][image]how to set year 1900 in place of 2?
Code I used for calendar:

Date Picker Image: I want to show year 1900 instead  of 2

```
private DatePickerDialog customDatePickerFrom() {
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListner, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        try {
            Field[] datePickerDialogFields = dpd.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) {
                if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
                    datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(dpd);
                    Field datePickerFields[] = datePickerDialogField.getType().getDeclaredFields();
                    for (Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                        if ("mDayPicker".equals(datePickerField.getName()) || "mDaySpinner".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                            datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                            Object dayPicker = new Object();
                            dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                            ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            dpd.getDatePicker().findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("day","id","android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    return dpd;
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Date what you want with **updateDate**:

```
datepicker.updateDate(int year, int month, int dayOfmonth);
```

Comment: thank you so much, this worked for me but after using date apears above datepicker. i'm adding image in qustion. how to removethat text.